# How do I use elements in a list as the index for a separate list?

Tags: python

```
pos = [
    ['string1', 1, 2, 3, 'string2', 4, 5],
    ['string1', 0, 0, 0, 'string2', 4, 5]
       ]

strings = [0, 4]
not_strings = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]

v = []
for items in pos:
    for i in not_strings:
        v.append( (items[i]) )

>>> v.append( max(items[i]) )
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I want to extract elements that is not strings from a nested list to a new list. Is there any way I can use elements in a list as the index for the original nested list?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the "max"?

Comment: Running your code I get `v` as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5]`

Comment: I suppose that was a typo on my part. The error message was copied directly from when my function returns an error. 

Even so, I should expect to append v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] with that line.

Comment: I don't understand. If your problem was just a typo you should delete the question. If you have a problem yet you should update the question to clarify it.

Comment: As Mark Meyer pointed out, apparently I've already succeeded at my original question. 

Was I supposed to delete this thread then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to remove the `strings` from the `pos` list and make a flat list from the numbers there. You could try something like this:

```py
v = []

# Loop over each item in pos
for item in pos:
    # Loop over each sub-item in item
    for sub_item in item:
        # Condition to ignore string subitems
        if type(sub_item) != str:
            v.append(sub_item)

# Get the biggest number in v
max_number = max(v)
```

This doesn't use indexes but it solves your problem.

Comment: I don't think you meant `string` — maybe `str`?

Answer (score 0):

try this, The `isinstance()` function returns True if the specified object is of the specified type here `int`

```
not_string = []

for v in pos:
    not_string.extend([x for x in v if isinstance(x, int)])

max([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5])
```